# Outlook not showing attachments

Tags: c#, outlook

I am using Outlook.Application and Outlook.MailItem object for opening Outlook in my C# desktop application. My outlook doesn't display attachments although when I send the mail to myself, I receive mail with attachments. But it is not showing before sending mail (when outlook is open). I am using Outlook 2007. Below is my code:

```
Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.NameSpace oNS = oApp.GetNamespace("mapi");
// Log on by using a dialog box to choose the profile.
oNS.Logon(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, true, true);


 // Create a new mail item.
        Outlook.MailItem oMsg =         (Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
......
 //Check if we need to add attachments
if (_files.Count > 0)
{
   foreach (string attachment in _files)
   {
             oMsg.Attachments.Add(attachment,Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue,null,null);
   }
}   

 oMsg.Save();
 oMsg.Display(false);
```

Comment: It would be good to format this more clearly.  I would do it myself but the edit button is grayed out.

Comment: The code is now formatted. thanks.

Comment: I was able to resolve above issue by replacing attachment line to below: oMsg.Attachments.Add(attachment, Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue,Type.Missing,Type.Missing);

Answer (score 0):

Of course, Type.Missing is used to omit the parameter and use the default value in COM add-ins.

Also I'd suggest breaking the chain of calls and declaring each property or method call on a separate line of code. It will allow to release each underlying COM object instantly.

Use [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject.aspx) to release an Outlook object when you have finished using it. This is particularly important if your add-in attempts to enumerate more than 256 Outlook items in a collection that is stored on a Microsoft Exchange Server. If you do not release these objects in a timely manner, you can reach the limit imposed by Exchange on the maximum number of items opened at any one time. Then set a variable to Nothing in Visual Basic (null in C#) to release the reference to the object. You can read more about that in the [Systematically Releasing Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb623945%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article in MSDN.